# Change Magento admin panel menu position

Tags: magento-1.9, backend

I want to change my custom module (named MODEL) menu position in Magento Admin panel. Right now it is added at last. I want something like this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks all for answers. I will vote for amit as he answered first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento is manage it menu item position by tag `<sort_order>`  and it this code is exit in `adminhtml.xml` file of your module.

Just change it value.

```
<sort_order/>
```

Each menu item `has a sort order. For top level menu items, lower numbers will sort further to the left, higher numbers to the right. For sub-menu items the sort is top/dow`n.

`<sort_order>Numerical value</sort_order>` in adminhtml .xml of your extension.

Example:

```
<menu>
        <mycustomtab module="jr_createadmincontroller" translate="title">
            <title>My Custom Tab</title>
<!-- need to change here  -->
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <index module="jr_createadmincontroller" translate="title">
                    <title>Index Action</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/custom</action>
                </index>
                <list module="jr_createadmincontroller" translate="title">
                    <title>List Action</title>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/custom/list</action>
                </list>
            </children>
        </mycustomtab>
    </menu>
```

More details at http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_controllers

Comment: its already 100. Any other solution?

Comment: just decrease it value

Comment: Upvote from me .For good question and Please add more details to your question

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add a config in here:

```
/app/code/local/Company/YourModule/etc
```

Call this file `adminhtml.xml`

Put the following code in there:

```
<config>
    <menu>
        <yourmodule module="yourmodule">
            <title>Navigation Link Title</title>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        </yourmodule>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Adjust the number in `sort_order` to suit your needs

Answer (score 2):

For an example, this is the code for `dashboard` menu that appears "first" in admin panel main menu section. If you look on the menu definition of this menu (Which is available in `adminhtml.xml` of core module `Mage_Adminhtml`), you can see that, it uses the node `sort_order` for positioning itself in the menu section.

```
<config>
    <menu>
        <dashboard translate="title" module="adminhtml">
            <title>Dashboard</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <action>adminhtml/dashboard</action>
        </dashboard>
       ....
   </menu>
</config>
```

Have a look on that `adminhtml.xml` file. You will get an idea what value should given for your custom menu in order to position it in desired location .